# SocketServer never exits

Tags: python, python-2.7, socketserver

I'm starting a simple TCP server using SocketServer:

```
class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    pass
...
server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
server_thread.daemon = True
server_thread.start()
try:
...
finally:
    server.shutdown()
```

However, after the program ends **it doesn't terminate and seems to be stuck**. It doesn't respond to keyboard events (CTRL-C) and the only way to exit is to call `os._exit(0)` or to just close the shell window.

I've searched a bit about it but I still don't see what I'm missing: The thread is marked as daemon, and the server is shut-down at the end.

I'm running Python 2.7.9 under Windows 8.1

Comment: Did you try: `server_thread.join()`

Comment: @ozgurv Good point. If the code reaches the end normally, it will terminate. However, if an exception is thrown (for example CTRL-C) it remains stuck with `server_thread.join()` (but not with `os._exit(0)`)

Comment: Perhaps the server creates other internal threads and/or perhaps you need to call `server.server_close()` in addition to `server.shutdown()`.  See: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socketserver.html#SocketServer.BaseServer.server_close

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-c raises `KeyboardInterrupt` exception and the issue is SocketServer internally catches the error but never bothers to come out. You can add an extra signal handler for `signal.SIGINT` & then call `server.start()`.
Like this,

```
import signal
import sys
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
     logger.log("DEBUG","You pressed Ctrl+C!")
     server.stop()
     sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
server_thread.start()
signal.pause()
```

Comment: This does not exactly work - it writes "You pressed Ctrl+C!" and remains stuck. But if I replace sys.exit(0) with os._exit(0) it does exit the application. Exiting with os._exit does not feel like a clean solution.

Comment: and btw I think it's `server.shutdown()` not `server.stop()`